# Display function graph on the web

Tags: charts

I would like to display a couple of function graphs in a web browser. That is, I have a few functions, like distribution or density functions, regularly generated by data analysis tools and I'd like to make those accessible via a web browser. They should be rendered as line charts, actual values displayed e.g. in a tooltip when hovering over the chart. The ability to zoom in would be nice but not essential. Also, a nice dashboard like arrangement would be nice. Now I have the data (each function represented as a list of floats), how do I best render them?

Generating static images might be an option, but they're not interactive at all. I see there are javascript frameworks to display charts, but I have the feeling there must be some ready-made solution out there to grab numbers from a file, or DB, or wherever, and show functions; hence, I don't want to start writing my own javascript. I thought about [Grafana](http://grafana.org), but that's time series oriented and my data is not time series. I thought about importing the data into Google spreadsheets and create charts there programmatically, but I'd like to have at least a few thousands data points per chart and am not sure if that would work out performancewise.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

use the simplest php Graph library. PHPMYGRAPH.

http://phpmygraph.abisvmm.nl/

Comment: Ah, instead of javascript, an unmaintaned PHP lib. Not sure if I'm better of with that ;-)

Comment: i am referring the simplest solution to your problem.